# Python plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a question about the plotting. I want to plot some data between ranges :

`3825229325678980.0786812569752124806963380417361932`
and 
`3825229325678980.078681262584097479512892231994772`

but I get the following error:

```
Attempting to set identical bottom==top results
in singular transformations; automatically expanding.
bottom=3.82522932568e+15, top=3.82522932568e+15
```

How should I increase the decimal points here to solve the problem?

Comment: If you fit one of the answers attend you needs you can accept them clicking on the arrow besides it or upvote them clicking on the up-arrow

Comment: also... you get +2 reputation for each accepted answer that is not yours...

Answer (score 5):

The difference between your min and max value is less than the precision an [eps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) of a double (~1e-15).

Basically using a 4-byte floating point representation you can not distinguish between the two numbers.

I suggest to remove all the integer digits from your data and represent only the decimal part. The integer part is only a big constant that you can always add later.

Comment: Thanks, in python it did not work, but for producing my initial data, I did it, and it seems nice now.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easiest to scale your data to provide a range that looks less like zero.

Comment: It's not a problem of scale, it's a problem of precision.